# SQL Database csv| ID's

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I have a question about linking ID's in a database.

this is the case:

we have multiple CSV files. These CSV-files each contain a Movie and the there by needed information. for example:

I have a CSV file for rating that contains the movie name and the rating.
I have a CSV file for runningtime that contains the movie and the running time.
I have a CSV file for Movie which contains the movie and the year.

the question:

how do I link the MovieID that i created from the Moviename in the movie csv to the rating and the running time.

also, i am using java to put csv into database like this:

```
String sqlRating = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'src/csv-files/Ratings.csv' into table Ratings FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";

String sqlMovie = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'src/csv-files/Movies.csv' into table Movies FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";
```

Comment: I think you would have to process each row separately rather than using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Read each line of `Ratings.csv`, query the database with the movie name and get the movie id and do an sql `INSERT` for the rating.

Comment: Already tried, but it takes way to long to process because of the size of my files.

Comment: You mean it would take hours or days? If it's a one time import then a few hours won't be a problem would it?

Comment: yeah you're right. i'll give it another shot thnx.